# autofac mvc3 with controller default constructor,need help?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, autofac

i am trying to imitate the sample given with using autofac, but constantly getting no parameterless constructor missing error for my contoller. what am i doing wrong should i create a modelbinder for the irepository?

here is how the bootstrapper looks like. mocked testers put in here it s just as in example does not really reflect the actual intention. there gonna a seperate test project.

```
Mock<iproductrepository> mock = new Mock<iproductrepository>();
mock.Setup(m => m.products).Returns(new List<product>()
                                        {
                                            new product() {name = "football", price = 25},
                                            new product() {name = "surf board",price = 179},
                                            new product() {name = "running shoes", price = 95}
                                        }.AsQueryable()

    );

builder.RegisterInstance(mock.Object).As<iproductrepository>();
builder.RegisterModelBinders(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());


var container = builder.Build();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

and here is controller simple

```
public class productcontroller : Controller
{
    private readonly iproductrepository _productrepository;


    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="productrepository"></param>
    public productcontroller(iproductrepository productrepository)
    {
        _productrepository = productrepository;
    }

    //
    // GET: /product.controller/

    public ViewResult list()
    {
        return View(_productrepository.products);
    }

}
```

getting this error

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object. Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code. Exception Details:
>   System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined
>   for this object. Source Error: An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding
>   the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the
>   exception stack trace below. Stack Trace: [MissingMethodException: No
>   parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +98
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean
>   fillCache) +241    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean
>   nonPublic) +69
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +67 [InvalidOperationException:
>   An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type
>   '*.productcontroller'. Make sure that the controller has

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Autofac in the method `builder.RegisterControllers` registers the controllers which name end with "Controller" with a capital C :

```
...
if (typeof (IController).IsAssignableFrom(t))
   return t.Name.EndsWith("Controller");
else
   return false;
...
```

So you need to rename your controller to `productController` (anyway in C# `ProductController` according to the [naming convenctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx)) or register the your controllers by "hand" in the container.

Comment: A good practical example of why you should stick with the standard naming conventions wherever possible.

Comment: goodness! thanks bunch. ain't know that these standards gonna be imposed.

Comment: Wow that's frustrating. Typo in the controller name. Not really a lesson in naming conventions a lesson in ignoring case for sure.